# Does the series $ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3} $ converges uniformly on $ \ \ \ [-1,1] \ $?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does  the series  $ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3} $ converges uniformly  on  $  \ \ \  [-1,1] \ $?

**Answer:**

$ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3} \\  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^2}{n^3}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n} \\ \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n^3}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n} , \ (\because |x| \leq 1 ) \\ = A+B $

Since both the series $ \ A,B \ $ are alternating series , both converges uniformly on $ \ [-1,1] \ $.

So the given series converges on $ \ [-1,1] \ $ uniformly.

**But I am not sure of my work.**

Please someone verify my work .

Comment: You cannot use inequality to alternate series, i mean your first $\leqslant$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct. Why would those inequalities be true?

You can prove that the series converges uniformly using [Dirichlet's test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence):

1. $\left(\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n\right)_{N\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded;
2. $\left(\frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is monotonic for each $x\in[-1,1]$;
3. $\left(\frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly to the null function.

Comment: What if we split this to two series? The first one is uniformly convergent by Weierstrass $M$-test, and the second one is simply a numerical convergent sequence?

Comment: The first equality is true because if $\sum_n A_n$ converges absolutely and $\sum_nB_n$ converges then $\sum_n(A_n+B_n)=\sum_nA_n+\sum_nB_n.$

Comment: But the "$\leq$ " in the Q is a non-sequitur.